# get data from json array to Table angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this json data:

```
     {
status: "SUCCESS",
data: [
{
FirstName: "Student ",
LastName: "1",
Id: 1,
ObjectState: 0
},
{
FirstName: "Student ",
LastName: "2",
Id: 2,
ObjectState: 0
    }
   }
  ]
}
```

I have tried like this,in my controller and in the view:
app.js:

```
.controller("etudCtrl",["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
        var i;

    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'MyURL'})
             .success(function (data) {

                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                $scope.paged = data[i].data; // response data 
                console.log($scope.paged+" $scope.paged");
        }
            $scope.currentPageStores= $scope.paged;
            console.log($scope.currentPageStores+"  values");

              console.log("success");
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log("data error ...");
     });
 }])
```

Students.html:

```
<table>
<thead>...</thead>
 <tbody data-ng-controller="etudCtrl">
   <tr ng-repeat="store in currentPageStores" >    
  <td align="center">{{store.LastName}}</td>
  <td align="center">{{store.FirstName}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and this what I get in console:

```
values
success
```

I didn't get any data in console or in the Table :(
any help please
thanks

Update:
I try with this:

```
 $rootScope.usersData = angular.toJson(data.data);
 console.log($rootScope.usersData+" my data");
```

I get all the data that I want to display in console

Update2:

```
 $http({method: 'GET', url: 'MyURL'})
             .success(function (data) {

       console.log(JSON.stringify(data)+"myData");

        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        $scope.paged = data.data[i]; // response data 
        console.log($scope.paged+" $scope.paged");
              }
.....
}
```

I get this in console:

```
{"status":"SUCCESS","data":[{"FirstName":"Student ","LastName":"1","Id":1,"ObjectState":0},{"FirstName":"Student ","LastName":"2","Id":2,"ObjectState":0}]}myData
```

Comment: can you show the log of whats being returned in success(function (data)----->whats the data here? if its object object use json stringify and log it. Can you

Comment: You had this set up properly in an earlier question that you must have deleted. Try `$scope.currentPageStores = data.data` and get rid of the loop

Comment: You have not written the closing tag of tr.

Comment: Seems to me it should be data.data[i] rather then data[i].data. At least according to the shown structure. In that case for cycle should be to data.data.length.

Comment: need the log of data!!! to come into any decisions regarding the need of loop or not.

Comment: I have tried data[i].data in the loop,and always I get nothing as a result in the Table Sir

Comment: Well yes, if you really get the above described object in response, then in parameter "data" of callback you get an object which contains array named data, so particular items should be accessed as data.data[i].

Comment: nono buddy, just the data from the success  $http({method: 'GET', url: 'MyURL'})
             .success(function (data) { console.log(data); whats in here --------------------> whats the data returned from the get. No need to loop around it just the plain data

Comment: If data.data contains really all you need, than it is exactly as I say. Maybe change "$http({method: 'GET', url: 'MyURL'}) .success(function (data)" to "$http({method: 'GET', url: 'MyURL'}) .success(function (response)" and then maybe response.data[i] and response.data.length will make more sense to you.

Comment: @user3821206 your loop is going to overwrite `$scope.paged` every iteration. Did you try what I suggested in second comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop around in controller. Try the following:

**Your Controller:**

```
.controller("etudCtrl",["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {


    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'MyURL'})
             .success(function (data) {
            $scope.currentPageStores= data.data;
            console.log($scope.currentPageStores+ "  values");

              console.log("success");
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log("data error ...");
     });
 }])
```

**Your student.html**

```
<table>
<thead>...</thead>
 <tbody data-ng-controller="etudCtrl">
   <tr ng-repeat="store in currentPageStores track by $index" >    
  <td align="center">{{store.LastName}}</td>
  <td align="center">{{store.FirstName}}</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a **PLUNKER** example of how you access when the data comes in an array as yours : http://plnkr.co/edit/Q9ewbH7XevsOQG0Yzv6B?p=preview

Comment: Simpler to skip the stringify ...console.log accepts multiple arguments

Comment: just wanted to skip the part where the type of [object] [object] may come into action and i have to teach to stringify the result to OP. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: It won't when you do `console.log("  values", object);`. Note difference between arguments and concatenation

Comment: i realized my mistake however if you just log the data.data it comes as an object and i wanted to show it as a string.

Comment: why...easier to work with objects in console. Can see hierarchy much easier

Comment: i like to see the object as a whole in string, depends upon choices :) By the way, i have seen you active helping people around since i started being active for about a week now, Thanks for being there for noobs like us and helping around. keep up the good work.

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,It's not working for me,I get this on console:[object Object],[object Object]  values

Comment: did you copy paste exactly and see if its working?? did you check the plunkr?

Comment: when I did:console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.currentPageStores)); I get in console the Data but I get nothing in the Table :(

Comment: there must be some error in your view than, cause if you get the data in the console means you have successfully binded it with $scope.currentPageStores. you can play with the plunker and see if you can make something out of it. Just out of curiosity can you paste the string that you have logged.

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,it works now,it was my error :D

Comment: Glad I could be of some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't print a object on console with another string.

use

```
console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.currentPageStores)+"  values");
```

or

```
console.log($scope.currentPageStores);
```

Comment: mmm but the problem is that he is not able being able to display in the view as well. Plus i don't think your answer solves the issue.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem in OP code and is really nothing more than a comment, not an answer